# When running a qemu-user chroot (say, a riscv64 chroot inside an amd64 host), is it possible to share the gpu and/or its drivers?

Tags: x11, qemu, chroot, opengl

I'm curious to see if I can, say, somehow reroute the riscv64 mesa drivers to the host's gpu. I've already got X11 and OpenGL applications working from the riscv64 chroot, but they end up using softpipe.
So, could it be possible to shim a riscv64 chroot's libGL.so or something while the host amd64 pc's libGL.so does all the work, so that the riscv64 chroot uses the actual gpu the amd64 host is using (in my case, an RTX 3060)?

EDIT: Originally, this question also asked about sharing the gpu itself and its actual drivers, instead of just shimming riscv64 mesa for the amd64 host. However, I discovered that NVIDIA doesn't have support (at least in their "official" drivers) for riscv64; only amd64 and arm64 (but now I'm curious if the gpu sharing thing can work in an arm64 chroot, but that's besides the point).

Answer (score 0):

Hardware drivers need access to `/dev/dri`; you should bind-mount that into your chroot. Once that’s done, if you have the appropriate parts of Mesa installed in your chroot, `libGL` should render using the hardware.

Comment: Unfortunately, although I did that, it seems the riscv64 chroot is still stuck using softpipe. I looked a bit more into this and it seems nvidia doesn't have drivers for riscv64.

Comment: Ah, since you mentioned Mesa drivers in your question, I thought you were using those, not NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I should have worded the question a bit better. Along with the gpu hardware sharing thing that I now found out can't happen (due to riscv64 not having NVIDIA drivers), I was also wondering if the chroot's libGL could be shimmed so that the host's libGL does the work instead, and I sorta typed this question late at night, and the "two-in-one" questions kinda merged into one.